# Call function on submit button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html text input and javascript code:

```
<input type="text" name="statuspopup" id="statuspopup" value="" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function SubmitTicketForm() {
    return CheckRequired();

    if($('#statuspopup').val() == '') {
        //do status popup here
        alert("status");
    } else {
        //just submit the form
        $('form1').submit();
    }
}
</script>
```

I then have this submit button:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="SubmitTicketForm();" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save" />
```

so it should show a javascript alert, but its not doing it.

Comment: That `if else` code code is unreachable (follows a return).

Comment: What is this "return CheckRequired();" ? your code will always stop there unless you encapsulate this line in a if-else statement

Comment: +1 for Miche.  when posting a question with small amount of code, it is good to include all of it so we don't guess. making assumptions when coding is not good practice.

Answer (score 2):

After you immediately return `CheckRequired()` function call your function stop executed. Supposed it returns BOOL value your function should look like this:

```
function SubmitTicketForm() {
    if( CheckRequired() === false ) {
        return false;
    }

    if($('#statuspopup').val() == '') {
        //do status popup here
        alert("status");
    } else {
        //just submit the form
        $('form1').submit();
    }
}
```

Also seems like your form selector is wrong. There is no such html element as `form1` if it is ID it should be `#form1` or `.form1` if it's class name

Comment: antyrat, this is wrong.  if not checked, no alert will happen.

Comment: and if checked form will ignore check and will submit anyway? Let's see what OP is prefer

Answer (score 0):

Function ends after return statement. Everything written after return in function is ignored. Place return at last.

```
<input type="text" name="statuspopup" id="statuspopup" value="" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function SubmitTicketForm() {
    if($('#statuspopup').val() == '') {
        //do status popup here
        alert("status");
    } else {
        //just submit the form
        $('form1').submit();
    }
return CheckRequired();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Then there should be some problem with your CheckRequired() function. Post it as well.

Comment: just removed it and looks like its now working fine. if the the if statement is true, how can i stop the form from submitting?

Comment: Replace `alert('status');` with `return false;` It'll stop the propagation.

Answer (score 0):

Put the return at the end of the function like this:

```
function SubmitTicketForm() {

    if($('#statuspopup').val() == '') {
        //do status popup here
        alert("status");
    } else {
        //just submit the form
        $('form1').submit();
    }

    return CheckRequired();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" onclick="SubmitTicketForm();" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function SubmitTicketForm() {
    if($('#statuspopup').val() == '') {
        //do status popup here
        alert("status");
    } else {
        //just submit the form
        $('form1').submit();
    }

     return CheckRequired();
}
</script>
```

now replace it thank you

Answer (score 0):

ok, another variant...
this ASSUMES that  checkrequired is checking the status of the checkbox(and returns a bool) and you only wish to have the alert if checkbox is not checked AND there is a value in statuspopup

```
function SubmitTicketForm() 
{
    if(!CheckRequired() && $('#statuspopup').val() == '') {
        //do status popup here
        alert("status");
        return false;
    } else {
        //just submit the form
        //$('form1').submit();
        return true; //it's a submit button...will submit by itself. if you want to 
             //manually submit with jquery, make it a button
    }
}
```

and don't forget to add a return to your onclick:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return SubmitTicketForm();" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save" />
```

once again, knowing what checkreturn is and why it's there would be useful!